# How to match a string that contains given characters in a given order?

Tags: javascript, regex

For example, I want to match my_very_nice_file.js, and I want to match it with these characters (mrie):

```
m: my
r: very
i: nice
e: file
```

As you see, these characters are followed by another, but they are not necessary together.

Just like [Sublime Text](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sublime_Text) 2 matches a file name. You can put any character, but one must follow the other.

Example:

[image]

I must do it in JavaScript. How can I do it?

If someone is interested, here is [the result of my question GitHub](https://github.com/tujamaica/QMatcher).

Comment: What about the "_" and the "." ?

Comment: I don't even understand the question

Comment: BTW, "consecutive" means they're next to each other.

Comment: Sorry, my english is very limited ):

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A straightforward pattern would be simply: `m.*r.*i.*e.*`. However, I assume that you do not only want to match files with the .js extension, and that the pattern matching should only match the filename and not its extenion. In this case, the simplified pattern would cause trouble if your extension contains any of those characters.

Food for thought: what about the following pattern?

```
m[a-z0-9\-_]*?r[a-z0-9\-_]*?i[a-z0-9\-_]*?e[a-z0-9\-_]*?\.[a-z]+
```

A brief explanation of what the pattern does:

- Ensures m, r, i and e to be in the right order
- Allows 0 or more characters (alphanumeric and underscore) to be in between each of them. The use of '?' denotes a lazy selection: the engine will try to match the least number of characters before moving on.

However, the pattern also assumes that you would only want to accept alphanumeric and underscore characters. You can add more symbols between the square brackets should you want to include other characters (but remember to escape the important ones).

To do the matching in JS, you can use:

```
var patt = /m[a-z0-9\-_]*?r[a-z0-9\-_]*?i[a-z0-9\-_]*?e[a-z0-9\-_]*?\.[a-z]+/gi;
if(fileName.match(patt)) {
    // If there is a match
} else {
    // If there is no match
}
```

**[Edit]** OP asked if it is possible to bold the highlighted characters. I suggested using the `.replace()` function:

```
var patt = /m([a-z0-9\-_]*?)r([a-z0-9\-_]*?)i([a-z0-9\-_]*?)e([a-z0-9\-_]*\.[a-z]+)/gi;
var newFileName = fileName.replace(patt, "<strong>m</strong>$1<strong>r</strong>$2<strong>i</strong>$3<strong>e</strong>$4");
```

For the sake of completeness, here is a [proof-of-concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/MGRdy/) ;)

Comment: Nice, that matches all at once. What if i want to turn the matched characters into bold ones like the image? I would done it using replace and returning '<strong>$1</strong>', but that works one match at the time.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is all you need:

```
m.*r.*i.*e
```