# How to replace all capture groups if it is generated dynamically?

Tags: javascript, regex

Consider the following code:

```
function Matcher(source, search) {

    var opts = search.split('');

    for (var i = 0; i < opts.length; i++) {
        opts[i] = '(' + opts[i] + ')';  
    }

    opts = opts.join('.*');

    var regexp = new RegExp(opts, 'gi');

    source = source.replace(regexp, function () {
        console.log(arguments);
        return arguments[1];
    });

    return source;
}
```

You call the function passing the source as the first parameter and what you need to match as the second one.

What i need is to replace all capture groups with a bold tag around the coincidence.

As an example, consider the following:

```
var patt = /m([a-z0-9\-_]*?)r([a-z0-9\-_]*?)i([a-z0-9\-_]*?)e([a-z0-9\-_]*\.[a-z]+)/gi;
var newFileName = fileName.replace(patt, "<strong>m</strong>$1<strong>r</strong>$2<strong>i</strong>$3<strong>e</strong>$4");
```

This code is an [answer from Terry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18749850/1048572) on my previous question but the problem here is that you need to know exactly what you want to replace, and i need it dynamically.

Any thoughts?

Comment: an example might help.

Comment: "you need to know exactly what you want to replace" well, yes. Otherwise it would be unpredictable and pointless. Do you mean you want to pass in a new needle to search for when you call the function, rather than have a hard-coded search-string to look for and replace?

Comment: it seems that i cant explain my self. The regex is builted dynamically. The user type a file name (for example) and for every character a capture group is created. I need to get that character and wrap it between a <strong> tag. That's all

Comment: So, an example input and desired output would be very useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you're creating the pattern the wrong way round. Instead of building `a(.*?)b(.*?)c`, you create `(a).*(b).*(c)` - with the capturing groups around the parts you already know. Better:

```
function wrapEachLetter(source, search, tag) {
    var opts = search.split('');
    tag = tag || "strong";

    return source.replace(new RegExp(opts.join("(.*?)"), 'gi'), function () {
        var str = '<'+tag+'>'+opts[0]+'</'+tag+'>';
        for (var i=1; i<opts.length; i++)
            str += arguments[i] + '<'+tag+'>'+opts[i]+'</'+tag+'>';
        return str;
    });
}
```

Example:

```
> wrapEachLetter("testExampleString", "tex", "b")
"<b>t<b><b>e<b>stE<b>x<b>ampleString"
```

Comment: I found some errors in the tag part but it was what i was looking for, thanks and here is the fix:
`function wrapEachLetter(source, search, tag) {
    var opts = search.split('');
    tag = tag || "strong";

    return source.replace(new RegExp(opts.join("(.*?)"), 'gi'), function () {
        var str = '<'+tag+'>'+opts[0]+'</'+tag+'>';
        for (var i=1; i<opts.length; i++)
            str += arguments[i] + '<'+tag+'>'+opts[i]+'</'+tag+'>';
        return str;
    });
}`

Answer (score 1):

Capture the delimiters too and then process only even subgroups, leaving odd ones as is:

```
s = "ABC---DEF---HIJ"
re = /(\w+)(.*?)(\w+)(.*?)(\w+)/
s.replace(re, function() { 
     return [].slice.call(arguments, 1, -2).map(function(a, n) { 
        return n & 1 ? a : "<strong>" + a + "</strong>" 
     }).join("") 
})

> "<strong>ABC</strong>---<strong>DEF</strong>---<strong>HIJ</strong>"
```

However, if your goal is to highlight only individual characters, it's much simpler this way:

```
str = "myfile.js"
letters = "mis"
re = new RegExp("[" + letters + "]", "gi")
str.replace(re, "<b>$&</b>")

> "<b>m</b>yf<b>i</b>le.j<b>s</b>"
```

or, without regular expressions:

```
str = "myfile.js"
letters = "mis"
str.split("").map(function(s) { 
     return letters.indexOf(s) >= 0 ? "<b>" + s + "</b>" : s 
}).join("")

> "<b>m</b>yf<b>i</b>le.j<b>s</b>"
```

Comment: See his previous question for the effect he's trying to achieve. He doesn't want to match all occurrences of these charaters, only a single match of them in this particular order. He wants to reproduce Sublime Text's filename matching feature.

Comment: @Barmar: my first snippet does exactly that, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, I was referring to the last two snippets. Sorry I wasn't clear.

Comment: Here is a finished example of what were my intentions:
[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tujamaica/rmznm/)

Comment: @tujamaica: well, it seems you wrote 3 times more code than needed. Take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/rmznm/11/

Answer (score 1):

```
var input = "aBcDeFgHiJk",
    match = 'be';
    str = '',
    reg = '',
    i = 0;

function escapeRegExp(c) {
    return c.replace(/[\-\[\]\/\{\}\(\)\*\+\?\.\\\^\$\|]/g, "\\$&");
}

// /(.*)(b)(.*)(e)(.*)/gi
// '$1<b>$2</b>$3<b>$4</b>$5'
for (var c in match) {
    if (i == 0) {
        str += '$' + ++i;
        reg += '(.*)';
        i++;
    }
    str += '<b>$' + i++ + '</b>$' + i++;
    reg += '(' + escapeRegExp(match[c]) + ')(.*)';
}


alert(input.replace(new RegExp(reg, 'ig'), str)); // <- a<b>B</b>cD<b>e</b>FgHiJk
```